# How to store current time for struct's field of type *time.Time in DataStore?

Tags: go

According to my requirements, I created one struct as -

```
type MyRule struct {
   CreatedAt    time.Time  `json:"createdAt" datastore:"createdAt,noindex"`
   UpdatedAt    *time.Time  `json:"updatedAt" datastore:"updatedAt,noindex"`
}
```

for createdAt field, I am able to store current time as-

```
MyRule.CreatedAt = time.Now()
```

However, the same thing does not work to store current time in `updatedAt` field of `MyRule` struct as it's type is `*time.Time` and not `time.Time`.
Here, I can't change field type of `updatedAt` because `*time.Time` allows me to accept nil as `updatedAt` value when I create any rule.

If I try to do this as-

```
 MyRule.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
```

It gives me below error-

```
 cannot use time.Now()(type time.Time) as type *time.Time in assignment
```

How can I store current time value in updatedAt field of type *time.Time and not time.Time

Comment: a quick refresher on pointers may help also: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Answer (score 5):

Note: one cannot get the address of a return value, so something like this will ***NOT*** work:

```
MyRule.UpdatedAt = &time.Now() // compile fail
```

To get the address of a value, it must be in an addressable item. So assign the value to a variable, like so:

```
t := time.Now()
MyRule.UpdatedAt = &t
```